# How to get first date in (Month,Quarter,Semi-annual,Year)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My required out put should be like when i pass 'january 2016'

it should return '01-01-2016'

for Quarter say Quarter 2, it should return '01-04-2016'

for Semi-annual say 2,it should return '01-07-2016'

for Year say 2016,it should return '01-01-2016'

Comment: @igor CREATE FUNCTION Startdate ( #mydate DATE )
 
RETURNS DATE
 
AS
 
BEGIN
 
DECLARE #output DATE
 
SELECT #output = DATEADD(dd, -DAY(#mydate) + 1, #mydate)
RETURN #output
 
END
 
GO   
SELECT dbo.Startdate('may 1993')

This is thing i have tried, that works fine for month and year !! i need likewise for quarter and semi-annual

Note: Replace # with @

Answer (score 0):

This article give you the answer:

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/04/sql-server-first-and-last-day-of-year.html

You may replace the `GETDATE()` with your own value to get the result.

Comment: In simplest way if i have given '3-APR-1993'

This is how the output should be 

Date_month = 01-04-1993 
Date_Quarter = 01-07-1993 
Date_year = 01-01-1993

Comment: @AhmedShining I dont get what you mean. Do you mean that you want to cast the result in some format like APR or Q2?

Comment: @AhmedShining You can use `DATENAME()` in your SQL statment

Comment: @AhmedShining For example, You can get `APR` with `CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(MONTH, SomeDateValue))`

Comment: @AhmedShining You can get `Q2` with the statment `Select ('Q'+DATENAME(q,SomeDateValue)) as Quarter from TableName`